# Error using Systeminfo or wmic, to remotely access

Tags: windows, wmic, system-information

Win-10\Pro = PCA
Win-11\Home = PCB
From Win-10\Pro to Win-11\Home. The user-name and password are the same for both machines; the user is the admin on both machines.

Example-01: Using Systeminfo

```
C:\Windows\system32>systeminfo /s PCB
Type the password for PCA\USR1:pwrd

ERROR: The user name or password is incorrect.
```

Example-02: Using wmic

```
 C:\Windows\system32>wmic
    wmic:root\cli>/node:PCB
    wmic:root\cli>/user:"PCB\USR1"
    Enter the password :pwrd

    wmic:root\cli>OS GET BuildType
    Node - PCB
    ERROR:
    Description = Access is denied.
```

I'm lost ...